# Pushing array values converted to lowercase to another array results in the other array not having the same amount of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am doing is retrieving an array of files from the server with ajax which I loop through and convert each value to lower case and then I push it to another array.

my new array:

```
var lowerCase = [];
```

Inside my ajax succes function:

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
    lowerCase.push(data[i].toLowerCase());
}
```

My `data` array has a length of 2460 but the `lowerCase` array only has a length of 471 for some reason.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I could fix this?

Comment: alert(data.length); what do you see?

Comment: There seems to be no error with your code. Can you show what data contains? that might help.

Comment: @ Danyal Sandeelo, It shows 2460 so the data value has the correct length.

Comment: @Douwe Pieter Reitsma what is the type of array `data`??

Comment: Is `data` an array or an object?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer, just filenames like `hello.mp3` , `hi.mp3` , `one.mp3`

Comment: @ KooiInc `data` look very beautiful :P

Comment: Try this instead of looping: `var lowerCase = data.map(function(v) { return v.toLowerCase(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem!

The problem was that the data variable wasn't an array.

I fixed this by converting the object to an array and then running my `toLowerCase()` loop on it.

```
var arr = $.map(data,function(el){
                return el;
            });

for (i in arr){
                lowerCase.push(arr[i].toLowerCase());
            }
```